# Which binary bits tells the file is password protected zip or rar file?

Tags: security

I am looking for the bit flags to detect the file is password-protected, not a regular `.zip` or `.rar`.

Comment: What OS/environment/language are you on?  Do you want to be able to figure this out from the shell, programmatically, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [zipinfo](http://www.info-zip.org/) and [unrar](http://www.rarlab.com/) to test whether a ZIP file is encrypted.  E.g.:

```
zipinfo -v file.zip |grep 'file security status:\s*encrypted'
unrar v -p- file.rar 2>&1|grep 'Encrypted file'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the header structure of rar [here](http://www.win-rar.com/index.php?id=24&kb_article_id=162)

And about the zip header structure [here](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

It helps to download the source code of opensource unpackers to read some code examples.